# Pull Data from shopping websites by URL

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Vuejs frame-work, and I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to pull from a link of shopping sites like Amazon and show me all the product details on Json, like there is on YouTube that when copying a link for example to WhatsApp, then the link loads information about the video.

someone know witch technology is recommended for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a web crawler such as dexi.io to extract the html of interest from any web page. Calling dexi can be done programmatically from your code.

Comment: You could also parse the DOM of the web page with XPATH or RegEx.